# Learning AngularJS and need to make a grouped list

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and am trying to make a web app. I am currently working through making a grouped list. I have a JSON file that holds several entries such as:

```
 {"title":"videoTitle",
"chapter":"2",
"section":"2",
"fileName":"videoFileName",
"extension":"m4v",
"quality":"SD"},
```

I have a simple controller

```
calcsuccessApp.controller('VideoListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('calcvideos/calc_video_list.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.videos = data;
    });
}]);
```

and I created a simple filter which can filter by chapter

```
calcsuccessApp.filter('inChapter', function () {
    return function (videos, chapter) {
        var filtered = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            var video = videos[i];
            if (video.chapter == chapter) {
                filtered.push(video)
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Now, in my html file I have the following

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <li ng-repeat="video in videos | filter:query | inChapter:2" class="list-group-item">
          {{video.chapter}}.{{video.section}}-{{video.title}}
            <a href="{{video.baseURL}}/{{video.fileName}}.{{video.extension}}">Watch me</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

This correctly filters all videos that are in chapter 2. What I would like to do is group the lists by chapter. I have been trying to figure out how to iterate through the list and group them but I have not been able to. I understand my overall knowledge is limited but I would appreciate any help you can direct my way or suggestions no where to look for a solution. I have done some searching and have found some solutions using external libraries but I would like to avoid using these at this time since I am focusing on learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it by a filter as you are trying to use.

Or else you can use the pref defined filter by https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby , and this is already tested. no need of testing